# Nestjs What is the right order for @Body(), @Params(), @Req(), @Res()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nestjs, backend

I want to access the `res` object to send `httpOnly` cookies and need to validate body with DTO.
but every time i try to do it something go wrong what is the right order for these params?

Answer (score 1):

There is no strict order that needs to be followed. Each controller method may use decorators for retrieving different things (see controller docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers)

### Example

Let's imagine you are building an endpoint for handling some kind of search using a POST request and a payload. Nest returns some results and sets cookies with the latest performed search timestamp.

That sounds like your requirements, right?

### Add cookie parser to nest application

Make sure you followed cookies documentation and installed all dependencies together and configured cookie parser middleware: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/cookies

### Search payload data transfer object (DTO)

```
import { IsInt, IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';

export class SearchBodyDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  searchPhrase: string;

  @IsInt()
  page = 1;
}
```

### Controller method

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Body, Controller, Post, Req, Res } from '@nestjs/common';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @Post('/search')
  async search(
    @Body() body: SearchBodyDto,
    @Req() req: Request,
    // passthrough:true here leaves response handling to framework.
    // Otherwise you would need to send response manually, like: `res.json({data})`
    @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response,
  ) {
    const currentTimestamp = new Date().toISOString();
    // Save to cookies current timestamp of search.
    res.cookie('lastSearch', currentTimestamp, { httpOnly: true });
    return {
      // Return last search timestamp and fallback to current timestamp.
      lastSearch: req.cookies.lastSearch ?? currentTimestamp,
      // Validated search phrase from DTO.
      searchPhrase: body.searchPhrase,
      // Page by default 1.
      page: body.page,
      // Some example search results.
      searchResults: ['water', 'wind', 'earth'],
    };
  }
}
```

### Result

Now when you do a request to the endpoint, you will see the latest search time in a response: [postman example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKigB.png), and also that value will be set to 'lastSearch' cookie.

The payload still will be validated using decorators on DTO.

Answer (score 0):

No order is required.

Also, they are [parameter decorator factories](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators), not parameters.